# Import data from a non public CSV into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a list of customer names i would like to import into my spreadsheet from a CSV file. Preferably every hour. 
The IMPORTDATA function works fantastic for this kind of operation.

The problem is that i don't want to store a CSV file with peoples names publicly. 
What would be your best suggestion to importing a CSV file to Google sheets without storing it on a publicly accessible URL? 
As i understand it there's no way to get Google Sheets to work via FTP?

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in your own Google Drive.

From there you could handle the import with Apps Script instead of import range